# Apache https proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm currently trying to set up a apache as a https proxy server enabling access to different https web pages. Any idea how to get this done? All documentation I've found so far handles reverse proxy only, but I'm not sure whether it is the right solution.

Comment: If this is for say internet or even internal clients to access servers that you are hosting, then a reverse proxy is what you want.

Comment: It is for clients without direct to internet. I want to provide them one internal address and map this to a particular internet domain.